# Refresh List After a New Entity is Added in Core Data for SwiftUI App

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am building a small app using SwiftUI and Core Data. I have a main view, which launches the sheet. The sheet allows me to add a new movie to the SQLite database through Core Data. But I am having a hard time to refresh the parent view once the sheet is dismissed.

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    @StateObject private var vm = MovieListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(vm.movies) { movie in
                    Text(movie.title)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Movies")
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Add Movie") {
                        isPresented = true
                    }
                }
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
                AddMovieView() 
            })
            .onAppear {
                try? vm.populateMovies()
            }.padding()
        }
        
    }
}
```

**AddMovieView**

```
struct AddMovieView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @StateObject private var vm = AddMovieViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Title", text: $vm.title)
            Button("Save") {
                do {
                    try vm.saveMovie()
                    dismiss()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to call vm.populateMovies() on the onDismiss function of the sheet from the ContentView?

Comment: You need an “@FetchRequest” or “NSFetchedResultsController”

Comment: you need to remove the view model objects and learn the property wrappers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `@FetchRequest` as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var movies: FetchedResults<Movie>
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    @StateObject private var vm = MovieListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(movies) { movie in
                    Text(movie.title)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Movies")
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Add Movie") {
                        isPresented = true
                    }
                }
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
                AddMovieView()
            })
            .padding()
        }
        
    }
}
```

You won't need a `populateMovies()` as the FetchRequest result is automatically populated.

Comment: Thanks! How will I do it if I don't use @FetchRequest. Sorry, this is for an article research project. NSFetchedResultsController can be an option.

Comment: I mean, you _could_, but just don't. Why would you write all the extra code when `@FetchRequest` does it in one line?

Comment: I 100% agree. I won't. This is just for an article, I wanted to cover how you would do it if you are using MVVM pattern. In the later part of the article, I will show a much better way.

Comment: @user19037628 In SwiftUI `@FetchRequest` is a MVVM pattern already.